# Why does MetaMask sdk for react native doesn't make wallet connection persistent?

Tags: react-native, metamask

eth_requestAccounts method returns accounts to me without problems but every time when I close the app I need to connect the wallet again. I'm using "@metamask/sdk": "^0.3.2". I found some examples but most of them are for React or outdated.